# How to uncheck all checkboxes in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem where all the checkboxes are marked, but my idea is when I select a button where it resets all the checkboxes, but it prescribes one by one, the idea is that I do everything with a click.
The functionality is wrapped in a recycreView.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderFiltro holder, int position) {  //Check
            if (categorias.length > 0 && position <= categorias.length){
                int i = position - 1;
                CheckBox [] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[i];

                // Esta parte es donde seleciona las letras el recycreView mustra el titulo
                holder.descripcion.setText(categorias[i]);
                holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(categoriasSel[i]);
                holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked ) {
                        //Cuando seleciono el checkbox me tra el valor True la inversa metrae False
                        //Nota intentar meter una variable boolean este code categoriasSel[i] != isChecked creo que puede funcionar
                       boolean filtradoCategoria = categoriasSel[i] != isChecked;
                       if (isChecked){
                           count++;
                           showFiltros();
                       }else {
                           count--;
                       }
                       if (isChecked== false && count<=0){
                            vanishFiltros();
                        }
                       if (filtradoCategoria){
                           categoriasSel[i] = isChecked;
                           itemsFiltrados = filtrar(isChecked);
                           productosAdapter.setValues(itemsFiltrados);
                           productosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       }

                        Log.d(TAG,"Esto es el Check" + categorias);

                       //This is the reset button
                        if (categorias.length > 0 && position <= categorias.length ){
                            btn_quitar_filtro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                  //holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                                    for (int a=0; a< categorias.length; a++){
                                        if (isChecked){
                                            holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                                            Log.d(TAG,"Btton Check FOR  " +holder.checkbox );
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                });


            }}
```

Comment: `categoriasSel[i]` For all `i`'s make it false. After that call notifyAdapterChanged().

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what you mean

Comment: What is the problem? You have `holder.checkbox.setChecked(categoriasSel[i]);` I hope you understand that code line. What it does. What it determines. So what if you want them to be not checked? What to do with all values in your categoriasSel array?

Comment: The values of the array categoriaSel makes it a boolean[] where it guarates the position that is I
What I did is this part but it doesn't work for me, the idea is that when I click on this setOnClickListener that all the checkboxes that are selected I reset them

Comment: `array categoriaSel makes it a boolean[] where it guarates the position that is` ??? No it determines if a checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: `the idea is that when I click on this setOnClickListener that all the checkboxes that are selected I reset them` Yes i know. I already knew. Well then do what i suggested you to do.

Comment: Not the one that determines if the box is selected is the`isChecked`

Comment: `isChecked`  tells you if a checkbox is checked or not. But at building up the items in your recycleview  `categoriaSel[]`  determines if the checkbox appears as checked or not.

Comment: Try to implement that code and what it does is that it unchecks the last check I do, it doesn't uncheck all the checks

Comment: Of course. You are only setting one array item to false. Now read my first comment where i suggested to set the whole array to false. You need a loop to do so..

Comment: so is that what you say?
`for (int a=0; a< categoriasSel.length; a++){
     holder.checkbox.setChecked(categoriasSel[i]);
 }
productosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in my first comment:

```
for (int a=0; a< categoriasSel.length; a++)
{    
 categoriasSel[a]=false;  
} 

productosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: That code will go in the part of the reset button?. The code would be something like this` btn_quitar_filtro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        for (int a=0; a< categoriasSel.length; a++) {
                                            categoriasSel[a]=false;
                                        }
                                        productosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                });`